# significant difference in mineral concentration between chemical analysis and values declared on packaging?

Tags: nonparametric, shapiro-wilk-test, chemometrics

I want to find out whether there was any significant difference in mineral concentration between chemical analysis and values declared on packaging.

After carrying out Shapiro-Wilk tests to assess the normality of the data obtained in the lab, results indicted that data was both parametric and non-parametric. I have carried out a sample t test to assess the parametric data. However, what non-parametric test would be suitable to find whether there was any significant difference in mineral concentration between chemical analysis and reference values?